# xampp not started on windows 7

Tags: mysql, sql-server, windows, windows-7, xampp

I download Xampp on windows 7 64bit , in windows also I had sql server  work together .
I had no idea why xampp not worked I guessed  it was because sql server used same port 80 , so I changed port of Apache server to 9090 but also not worked .
How to fix that ?

[image: Xampp Error]

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues"*

Comment: i noted that but error file is empty and event error not clear

Comment: Xampp version 1.7.3 is a stable version for windows 7 64 bit. I've been using Xampp version 1.7.3 in my windows 7 64 bit. Don't change the port of apache and mysql. Check your softwares which uses port 80 inorder to do communication eg skype or other softwares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set back your ports to their original settings which should be Port: 80. Check if you have Skype installed on your PC. If you Skype, go to your settings and check for the Skype port and disable it from using Port 80. That way you'll be set to go. If after that the issue continues then you can run a check to know what other software communicate using Port 80.

Comment: I had No skype on my pc , but I had Sql server ?!

Comment: Disable SQL server so you don't have it conflicting with you XAMPP installation then restart to see what happens next

Comment: I disabled all services of Sql server also same result not worked

Comment: What errors are you getting now? What modules are on and those off?

Comment: Omni thanks to follow my question all details in qustion  screenshot

Comment: Check well that there are no errors dumped in your error log. If none and you think all is well, uninstall and install again. Possibly restart after uninstall before installing again to clear off any memory dumped files. Keep us posted for further helps

Comment: Yes finally it's work I download other old version and worked , I Guss the problem in  latest version (beta ver )

Comment: Well done! Keep it up :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26293/discussion-between-ahmad-samilo-and-omnipotens)